# How configure 2 Lan cards in Windows 7/8 pc one to connect to Internet and other to Local Network

Tags: windows-7, local-area-network, internet, voip, windows-sbs-2011

I am about to install a dedicated VOIP server in our office. It is a 3CX pbx system on Windows 7/8 machine. The environment currently is a Windows SBS 2011 with 8 client machines. I want to use a dedicated broadband connection for the PBX (3CX) box, but the box also needs to be accessible in the local network as we will be using IP Phones and software IP phones. How configure two network cards on PBX box, so that one will be always used to connect to our SIP host over the Internet and the other will be connected to local network accessible from other client pc to connect to the pbx system. It must be noted that currently the Windows SBS 2011 acts as the Primary Domain Controller and gateway for all the client machines. 
       I cannot use a load balancer as it will conflict and cause issues within the current setup of our SBS2011 as it is also our Exchange Server. 
Any input is much appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

- Physically connect the interfaces to the correct networks
- Give the interfaces IP addresses, do not set a gateway on the LAN adapter
- If your LAN has more than a single subnet/vlan, then you will have to setup static routes for your networks with routes pointing at the appropriate router.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Well I am a developer and understand little about network. How can I findout if the lan has more than single subnet? And adding to it if I don't join the pbx server to domain will it be accessible from other machines in the domain.?  Appreciate your time and help

Comment: Talk to your sysadmin?  If you don't have a sysadmin, check for the documentation.